# Leave out empty views in array adapter

Tags: android

My array adapter look like this:

http://www.airbrush-ernst.nl/domo1.jpg

I'm not alowed too post an image :(

I want too leave out the empty views. I'm just started with android and I tried to manipulated the getview but this doesn't work.

Can anyone help me out.

Tnx

Here is my code

```
    public class MyCustomAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<String> {

    public MyCustomAdapter(Context context, int textViewResourceId,
            String[] objects) {
        super(context, textViewResourceId, objects);
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        // return super.getView(position, convertView, parent);

        View row = convertView;


        if (row == null) {
            LayoutInflater inflater = getLayoutInflater();
            row = inflater.inflate(R.layout.row, parent, false);

        }

        TextView label = (TextView) row.findViewById(R.id.rowText);
        label.setText(locatie[position]);
        ImageView icon = (ImageView) row.findViewById(R.id.icon);

        if (position == 0 && on1) {
            icon.setImageResource(R.drawable.bulpon);
        } else if (position == 1 && on2) {
            icon.setImageResource(R.drawable.bulpon);
        } else {
            icon.setImageResource(R.drawable.bulpoff);
        }

        return row;

    }
}




String[] locatie = { "Huiskamer - achter TV", "Huiskamer - kast",
        "Huiskamer - achter", "Keuken", "Voordeur", "", "", "", "",
        "", "" };

/** Called when the activity is first created. */
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    haaldata();
    // setListAdapter(new MyCustomAdapter(Binnen.this, R.layout.row,
    // locatie));

}

@Override
protected void onResume() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onResume();

    SharedPreferences getPrefs = PreferenceManager
            .getDefaultSharedPreferences(getBaseContext());
    String prefM1 = getPrefs.getString("menu1", "");
    if (!prefM1.trim().contentEquals(""))
        locatie[0] = prefM1;
    String prefM2 = getPrefs.getString("menu2", "");
    if (!prefM2.trim().contentEquals(""))
        locatie[1] = prefM2;
    String prefM3 = getPrefs.getString("menu3", "");
    if (!prefM3.trim().contentEquals(""))
        locatie[2] = prefM3;
    String prefM4 = getPrefs.getString("menu4", "");
    if (!prefM4.trim().contentEquals(""))
        locatie[3] = prefM4;
    String prefM5 = getPrefs.getString("menu5", "");
    if (!prefM5.trim().contentEquals(""))
        locatie[4] = prefM5;
    String prefM6 = getPrefs.getString("menu6", "");
    if (!prefM6.trim().contentEquals(""))
        locatie[5] = prefM6;
    String prefM7 = getPrefs.getString("menu7", "");
    if (!prefM7.trim().contentEquals(""))
        locatie[6] = prefM7;
    String prefM8 = getPrefs.getString("menu8", "");
    if (!prefM8.trim().contentEquals(""))
        locatie[7] = prefM8;
    String prefM9 = getPrefs.getString("menu9", "");
    if (!prefM9.trim().contentEquals(""))
        locatie[8] = prefM9;
    String prefM10 = getPrefs.getString("menu10", "");
    if (!prefM10.trim().contentEquals(""))
        locatie[9] = prefM10;



    setListAdapter(new MyCustomAdapter(Binnen.this, R.layout.row, locatie));

}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
    MenuInflater blowUp = getMenuInflater();
    blowUp.inflate(R.menu.cool_menu, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    switch (item.getItemId()) {
    case R.id.aboutus:
        Intent i = new Intent("nl.ernst.splash.ABOUT");
        startActivity(i);

        break;
    case R.id.preferences:
        Intent p = new Intent("nl.ernst.splash.PREFS");
        startActivity(p);
        break;
    case R.id.exit:
        finish();
        break;

    }
    return false; // onOptionsItemSelected verwacht een boolean terug dus
                    // geef maar wat terug :-)
}

@Override
protected void onListItemClick(ListView l, View v, int position, long id) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    // super.onListItemClick(l, v, position, id);
    String selection = l.getItemAtPosition(position).toString();
    Toast.makeText(this, selection, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}

private void haaldata() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    URL textUrl;
    try {
        textUrl = new URL(outSource);
        BufferedReader bufferReader = new BufferedReader(
                new InputStreamReader(textUrl.openStream()));
        String StringBuffer;
        String stringText = "";
        while ((StringBuffer = bufferReader.readLine()) != null) {
            stringText += StringBuffer;
        }
        bufferReader.close();

        Toast.makeText(this, stringText, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

        String str[] = stringText.split(",");
        if (str[0].equals("1")) {
            on1 = true;
        } else {
            on1 = false;
        }

        if (str[1].equals("1")) {
            on2 = true;
        } else {
            on2 = false;
        }

        // msg.setText(stringText);
    } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block e.printStackTrace();

    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();

    }
}
    }// class Binnen
```

Comment: It's okay to delete the "auto-generated" comments...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in you adapter you want to create this method

```
public class MyCustomAdapter extends BaseAdapter{
...
public int getCount() {
    return 5;//or however many you want to have total
}
...
}
```

Comment: the get count tells the view how many items it needs to display, and then it will request them from the "public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent)" method

Comment: Update your answer, don't comment on it.

Comment: I commented because that wasn't related to his question, it was just additional information.

Comment: @Mikelsrael I'm just a beginner. Where (how) do I override this.I looked for an override methode but it doesn't exist.

Comment: @ernst I just checked my code where I use it and actually didn't use the override, so just try putting that in your MyCustomAdapter, and make sure you setAdapter(MyCustomAdapter).  see my edits.

Comment: Tnx Mikelsrael  It works but i had too override it. You saved me day of work! HAPPY NEW YEAR !

Comment: my pleasure.  Please also accept it as an answer if it worked out :)  Happy new year of androiding!

Comment: I don't want too make this a long discussion but..  How do you accept an answer?I couldn't find this in the FAQ.  (I will delete this comment later )

Comment: no problem, there should be a grayed out check next to the answer.  When you click it it should turn green.  You can also upvote the answer by clicking on the up arrow, once you have enough points.